# Has the Sentinel-1 InSAR workflow from SNAP been integrated into GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I'm trying to do some batch InSAR processing on Sentinel-1 image stacks. My desktop doesn't have processing power to run the tool in a timely matter. If I upload the complex SLC data to my Google Earth engine storage is there a SNAP equivalent InSAR tool I can run?

Answer (score 2):

Google Earth Engine does not currently have functionality for InSAR processing.

Answer (score 0):

GEE currently only has GRD products for processing